# How can I implement univariate Nadaraya–Watson regression for prediction？

Tags: regression, predictive-models, univariate, nadaraya-watson

How can I implement univariate Nadaraya–Watson regression for prediction？
And what is the  $x ,x_i$, and $y_i$? How can I select the $x ,x_i$, and $y_i$？ The sample for prediction and the shape of sample is like $[12,34,5,23]$.It is a list.

$$\hat{m}_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{K\left( \frac{x-x_i}{h}\right)Y_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n K \left( \frac{x-x_j}{h}\right)}$$

Comment: You can check out [this](https://github.com/gerdm/prml/blob/master/chapter06/kernel-regression.ipynb) Jupyter notebook for a Python implementation.

Answer (score 0):

$(x_i,y_i)$ are the training data set.

$x$ is the new point that you want to make prediction at that value. In your case, $x$ takes value from $[12, 34, 5, 23]$.

Comment: Can you recommend me the relevant code to see it?  Thanks！

Comment: is this a homework assignment?

Comment: no ,this is the first autoregressive algorithm I have encountered and I want to implement it. I am curious about its predictions  work on univariate datasets, especially time series issues.

Comment: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16776/128610) is a relevant discussion.